# regex match all words in a python list not preeced by @

Tags: python, regex

I am currently using this code to search a list for all words but I need it to disregard those words preceded by @.

`[@apples, peaches, oranges, @guava]`

return just:

`[peaches, oranges]`

`words = re.compile(r'\w+')`

Could anyone help me in to do the same?

Comment: That's not a valid list. Are there quotes around each item of the list `["@apples", "peaches", "oranges", "@guava"]` (that's what the answerers that proposed a non-regex solution seem to think) or is in in fact a Python string `"[@apples, peaches, oranges, @guava]"`?

Answer (score 6):

Why regex it seems a rather simple task without it and regex seems more burdensome then needed, why not this...

```
f = []
for w in l:
    if not w.startswith("@"):
       f.append(w)
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
[x for x in l if not x.startswith('@') ]
```

being `l` your original, unfiltered list.

Or if you want a generator instead of an actual list, replace the square brackets with parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a negative look-behind. A pattern like this should work:

```
(?<!@)\b\w+\b
```

Note the `\b` (word boundaries) are there to ensure that it matches the whole word—without them it would match `pples` and `uava`.

Comment: As OP is talking about a list of words, wouldn't a `find('^[^@]')` suffice?

Comment: @Hyperboreus If OP is talking about finding multiple words inside a single string, then no. If OP is talking about a a list of strings, each containing a single word, then the two other answers are far more elegant.